# Low internal memory led to installation error

Tags: insufficient-memory, logging

OK, so this is the problem. I own a lenovo idea tab A3000, with no SIM cards inserted( that results in impossibility of using a dial pad) but rooted. Android version 4.2.2 .
 Like many other users, I was recommended to clean dumpstate/logcat but as I just said I wasn't able to use the dialer. Living in a country with adb help restrictions set by Google, that is not the solution for me either. I just managed to use clean master and SD maid to clean any possible system log files that were unnecessary but it seems due to low memory error that the package installer stucks me with, they, too, have failed.
Because of what has just been told, I'm unable to install busybox or any root installer app. I got so desperate I came over to ask.
I sense there are numerous solutions to this state yet I'm not aware of them.
ROM memory: 91 megabytes left
SD card available but not inserted
Internal memory : 714 megabytes left

Comment: *"Living in a country with adb help restrictions set by Google"* - that's interesting (as someone from the US). What restrictions are placed on Help by Google?

Comment: Error 403. Your client doesn't have permission to get URL blah blah blah...!

Comment: That's interesting. May I ask what county you are in when you experience it? Also, is that being returned from Google, and not some proxy? Have you tried to make the request with HTTPS, and inspect the certificate? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I humbly request any possible solution to this problem, and yes. The error is being returned from Google.

Comment: I can't answer on the adb part of the question,  but on the low memory - have you erased the contents of the .thumbnail folder in the DCIM folder?  Usually hogs up alot of space.

Comment: I can be sure of one thing and that is that there are no thumbnail files, windows junk files and any trivial annoyances. Who knows, maybe it's not only about dumpstate/logcat....

Comment: 714 MB on internal memory (not internal SDcard) should be more than enough. The "insufficient memory" error is usually triggered at 25 MB and below, and internal storage (aka "phone storage") the only thing affecting it. Have you checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)?

Comment: Yes sir, I now just did. The point is, there seems to be a systematic malfunction or something; because I witness my crash logs erased almost every 2 days or so with clean master. I wonder, will I be able to install a root installer after I uninstalled package installer?

Comment: Any body who can answer? Emptied space up to a point that I have 1.4 gigabytes free space, but I still get this error from package installer!